# Keep world within viewport bounds

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I am currently trying to create a 2D side scroller and i currently have my "world" drawing (a large white box for the time being), but i cannot figure out any relationship between the edge of the world map and the edge of the viewport to ensure that the viewport is always fully covered by the map.

My basic world drawing code is:

```
void drawTiles(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 500; j++) 
        {           
            glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(j, -i, 0);

            glBegin (GL_QUADS);
            glTexCoord2d(0.0, 0.0);
            glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

            glTexCoord2d(1.0, 0.0);
            glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

            glTexCoord2d(1.0, 1.0);
            glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);

            glTexCoord2d(0.0, 1.0);
            glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
            glEnd();
            glPopMatrix();
        }
    }
}

void display(void)
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glLoadIdentity(); 
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(camX, camY, -20); //translate back a bit to view the map correctly (our camera)

    drawTiles(); //draw our tiles

    glPopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60, (GLfloat)w / (GLfloat)h, 1.0, 100.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch(key)
    {
    case 'w':
        camY -= 0.25;
    break;
    case 's':
        camY += 0.25;
    break;
    case 'a':
        camX += 0.25;
    break;
    case 'd':
        camX -= 0.25;
    break;
    }
}
```

How would i go about ensuring that when I use WASD and on viewport resize, that i do not translate beyond the bounds of the map (currently 500x50 tiles)?

Comment: Do you really want to use the perspective projection? It's definitely possible, but I wonder if you're making things harder than they are.

Comment: i started using opengl and learning 2d rendering about 25 minutes ago, if you have anything you can do to make things easier, feel free to point them out

Answer (score 1):

If you have a planar scene (2D only), it should be sufficient to use an orthographic projection transformation. The projection transformation determines the camera's parameters. In the current state (with the perspective projection) you have a usual pin hole camera with a vertical opening angle of 60°.

An orthographic projection is defined by its edges. Let's say you want your camera to "see" two units to the left, 3 units to the right, 1 unit up and 4 units down. This would be possible, although it might not be reasonable in your case.

The current perspective camera "sees" about 11.5 units up and down. The according width can be calculated from the window dimensions (we do not want to stretch the image). So instead of `gluPerspective`, use the following:

```
float halfHeight = 11.5f;
float halfWidth = halfHeight * (GLfloat)w / (GLfloat)h; //based on window aspect ratio
glOrtho(-halfWidth, halfWidth, halfHeight, -halfHeight, -1, 1);
```

If you want to change the visible area, you just need to adjust the `halfHeight`. The `-1` and `1` are the znear and zfar plane. Everything that is between these planes is visible. Everything else will be cut off. But since you have only 2D content, this should not be relevant.

In your call to `glTranslatef(camX, camY, -20);`, set the z-coordinate to 0. This is not needed any more, because we have an orthographic view.

Now if you want to check if the map is still visible, do the following. I'll just show the exmple of checking the left/right boundary. The vertical case is similar:

```
//The camera can see from camX-halfWidth to camX+halfWidth
//You might want to make halfWidth and halfHeight class variables
float leftMapBoundary = 0;
float rightMapBoundary = 500;
//the camera must be 
//  * at least halfWidth right of the left boundary and 
//  *  at least halfWidth left of the right one:
if(camX < leftMapBoundary + halfWidth)
    camX = leftMapBoundary + halfWidth;
if(camX > rightMapBoundary - halfWidth)
    camX = rightMapBoundary - halfWidth;
```

Add the code after the `switch` in your keyboard function or whenever you move the camera.

Comment: I have been advised against the use of `glOrtho` as it has been depreciated and is not available in gl3/4 or gles2. Is there a way of doing this without `glOrtho`?

Comment: nevermind, found out how to re-implement glOrtho for gl3/glex compatibility from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131037/how-do-you-implement-glortho-for-opengles-2-0-with-or-without-tx-ty-tz-values-f

Comment: Most of the stuff you use is deprecated (`glPushMatrix`, `glVertex3f`, `glMatrixMode`...).

Comment: If you are interested in using in using only non-deprecated OpenGL code without having to write all of the matrix stuff from scratch you can use a library like GLM which implements most of the matrix functionality that has been deprecated.